# html and css background url image compacted

Tags: html, css

I created a web page image fills the screen 100%.
but, Problems occurred.
I want to fill up the picture on a Web page, as shown below:

[image: background.png]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#section
{
    margin-top:240px;
    margin-left:140px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#top-slogan
{
    width:100%;
    height:953px;
    background: url('background.png') center;
}
#top-header
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:133px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-slogan" class="wrapper">
    <div id="top-header" class="section">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The results came out, there are some problems.
Without being tightly filled, the image is repeated.
I want a solution.

I want delete "This part":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can add this style
```

```css
#top-slogan{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size : cover;
background position : center center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add no-repeat. Then it won't repeat.
" background-repeat: no-repeat;"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#section
{
    margin-top:240px;
    margin-left:140px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#top-slogan
{
    width:100%;
    height:953px;
    background: url('backgroung.png') center;
    repeat:no-repeat;
}
#top-header
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:133px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-slogan" class="wrapper">
    <div id="top-header" class="section">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can scale this image by setting it's width and height . 

    #top-slogan

     {
        width:100%;
        height:953px;
        background: url('backgroung.png') center;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 repeat:no-repeat;
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can scale this image by setting it's width and height .

```
#top-slogan

 {
    width:100%;
    height:953px;
    background: url('backgroung.png') center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this One

```
#top-slogan
{
width:100%;
height:953px;
background: url('background.png') no-repeat  center;
background-size :cover;
}
```